# How to use the Tikkun HaKlali?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, tehilim-psalms, shemos-sacred-names, breslov, repentance-teshuvah

Not too long ago I bumped onto a video on YouTube by user Shaarei Binah entitled “Tikkun HaKlali General Rectification of the Soul with Kavvanot”.

I was looking at the video itself, in the description and in the comments to see how is it supposed to be used, and I couldn’t find the answer.

I was wondering if you could help me. Do you have any idea?

What does it mean to meditate on Tehillim = El + Elohim and what to do when before each new Tehillim a name of one of the Sefirot appears?

Why does the Tetragrammaton come with a different nikkud each time a new Sefirot appears (I haven’t checked them all – I noticed it only recently), and is there a rule why is a particular letter at the bottom where what appears to be a tetractys emphasized? There are ten letters, as many as there are the Sefirot.

Some Hebrew letters are bigger than others while the verses from the Tehillim are running.

There should be an explanation somewhere, I presume, but so far I couldn’t find it.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Tikun Haklali was originally taught by Rebbe Nachman of Breslov as a rectification for the sin of zera levatala, particularly keri. It is also a "general rectification" (hence its name) for other sins. A person should have the intention of repentence while reciting the words of the Tehillim. That is all.

The "changes" you are talking about are not unique to Tikun Haklali nor are they even universal in all printings of it. Enlarged letters, sefirot, etc. are common in many Edot Hamizrach siddurim.

A person well-learned in kabbalah could explain the meanings of each individual sefirah but it is not something that can be or should be summarized online. The average person does not have the knowledge to even begin to understand such things, and should therefore keep it simple. After all, Rebbe Nachman did teach about the value in simple devotion.